# How to test a custom Laravel console command without of installing full framework?

Tags: php, laravel, console, laravel-artisan

I am developing a custom Laravel console command that distributes using composer and packagist.

So, **this package doesn't have full laravel framework installed**.
Instead of this the package uses separated packages like `illuminate/console` and `illuminate/support`.
This packages gives me the code completion, but I can't use advanced laravel testing possibilities like:

```php
$this->artisan('question')->expectsQuestion()
```

Because my tests extend from base phpunit TestCase instead of laravel's TestCase.
Because `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` requires implementation of the `createApplication()` method that provides a bootstrapped application.

**But I don't have application** installed, so, I can't implement this method.

How can I create `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` if I don't have full framework installed?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your test class is extending `Laravel\Lumen\Testing\TestCase`.

Then add this method to it:

```
    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Laravel\Lumen\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        return require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    }
```